# How to use 3D transformation matrices with GLM old version that has simd functions

Tags: c++, 3d, transformation, glm, simd

I need matrix 3D transformation, model transformation i.e scale-rotate-translate and then that model into world space so model-projection-view matrices.

I need it with GLM specified simd vectors and matrices according to their old version. 
But I can only find transformation functions without simd vectors or matrix in examples like this

```
#include <glm/vec3.hpp> // glm::vec3
#include <glm/vec4.hpp> // glm::vec4
#include <glm/mat4x4.hpp> // glm::mat4
#include <glm/gtc/matrix_transform.hpp> // glm::translate, glm::rotate, glm::scale, glm::perspective
glm::mat4 camera(float Translate, glm::vec2 const & Rotate)
{
glm::mat4 Projection = glm::perspective(glm::radians(45.0f), 4.0f / 3.0f, 0.1f, 100.f);
glm::mat4 View = glm::translate(glm::mat4(1.0f), glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, -Translate));
View = glm::rotate(View, Rotate.y, glm::vec3(-1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f));
View = glm::rotate(View, Rotate.x, glm::vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f));
glm::mat4 Model = glm::scale(glm::mat4(1.0f), glm::vec3(0.5f));
return Projection * View * Model;
}
```

I need it something like this

```
 glm::detail::fmat4x4SIMD MatrixMultiply()
    {
        glm::detail::fmat4x4SIMD m(1.0f);
        glm::detail::fmat4x4SIMD m1(1.0f);
        m1 = m1 * m;
        return m1;
    }
```

But If I try to give glm::lookAt, glm::rotate with fvec4SIMD/fvec4x4SIMD it gives me error that these built in functions does not support simd.

Any idea how to do this?